# Does God know about future & what is the proof of it in Qur'an?

Tags: quran, allah, future

Many people believe that God knows about future. However, I am having hard time finding any relevant script in Qur'an that clearly indicates that.

Comment: now you are satisfied ?or still some doubts as American Muslim has answered you and presented some verses from Quran ,when Allah knows everything and also he bestowed knowledge of unseen to Prophets then no doubts should be left in it.

Comment: @servant I guess the verses do indicate God's knowledge of future. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion of Past, Future and Present are relative to us humans. Allah has total control of everything, including such concepts for he was the one who created them:

[image]

> Allah is the Creator of all things, and He is, over all things, Disposer of affairs. [39:62]

Allah created us, the past and the future is known to him since he is all time. The quran Also says:

[image]

> [He is] Knower of the Ghaeeb [future and unseen] and the witnessed, the Grand, the Exalted. [13:9]

Allah also says:

[image]

> Indeed, Allah [alone] has knowledge of the Hour and sends down the rain and knows what is in the wombs. And no soul perceives what it will earn tomorrow, and no soul perceives in what land it will die. Indeed, Allah is Knowing and Acquainted. [31:34]

As you can see the hour (day of judgment is in the future, thus Allah knows the future).

Comment: I don't think verse [39:62] indicates anything about God's knowledge of future however rest 2 verse do, Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to the brother‘s question is “yes, Allahul-‘Aleem knows the future”, but that‘s a deep question that begs for more than a simple answer because of the element of our limited free will. Free will  enables us to choose many different courses of action. Each option that we have to choose from has within it its own possible future. Allah‘s knowledge encompasses all alternative possible futures. For example, consider when Allah tells us about the previous peoples He destroyed. In 71: 9-12 Prophet Nuh makes his people aware of a possible positive future awaiting them if they CHOSE to believe in Allah and mend their ways. And we know that their freedom to choose was authentic and that the promised good future was a certainty because Allah showed mercy to Prophet Yunus‘s people when they CHOSE to obey their prophet (37: 139 - 148). I find this to be an important point because some people try to argue the point, “well if Allah has perfect knowledge then He knew that some people were definitely destined to go to Hell” as if it is Allah‘s knowledge binding them to the path leading to the Fire. No! Allah‘s knowledge is perfect AND His justice is perfect. “It was not We that wronged them. They wronged their own souls” 11: 101. Yes, we wrong ourselves by the decisions we make. That is my understanding of the matter, but Allah knows best.