# Does Allah know the future?

Tags: quran, tafseer, future

According to the Quran, Allah is all-knowing. But does it mean that He knows all the future as well? Does it mean than when He created everything He did so while already knowing everything that would have happened?

Comment: This question actually is "Does it mean than when He created everything He did so while already knowing everything that would have happened?" so I don't think it's duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, one of Allah's names is

> Al Alim (العليم) The All Knowing, the Omniscient

Allah knows everything, everything that happened, happening, or will happen is already written in a book :

> And the record [of deeds] will be placed [open], and you will see the
>   criminals fearful of that within it, and they will say, "Oh, woe to
>   us! What is this book that leaves nothing small or great except that
>   it has enumerated it?" And they will find what they did present
>   [before them]. And your Lord does injustice to no one.
>
> Surat al-Kahf

You can read more about the question here : [Does God know about future & what is the proof of it in Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/26287/does-god-know-about-future-what-is-the-proof-of-it-in-quran)

Answer (score 0):

The future itself is something that Allah created; it includes anything such as light, place, love or hate.

Everything that is subject or not (mental) is created by Allah, and the creator knows everything about them.